# find software driver for old external maxtor hdd for win10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, external-hard-drive

i have old hard drive, 160gb from Maxtor company 'black armor', it's old and apparently based on other answers on forums it's incompatible on win10, it's compatible in win7,8.
https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/fa-go-desk-xtreme-sw-master/

here in this thread, -us/windows/forum/all/upgraded-to-windows-10-issue-with-using-maxtor/139b3d8a-7864-460b-8396-2bcc4b14c8d8

it says they can't find any webpage even on the maxtor's official website about drivers.

I tried uninstalling drivers according to various youtube tutorials.
standard online automatic search from windows update manager did not help.

how to tackle the issue of finding drivers for old hdd drive?

Comment: I don't know of any hard drive that needed 'drivers'. What happens if you just plug it in? Are you just trying to salvage data from it as a one-off process? I wouldn't attempt to put a drive that old back into active service.

Comment: https://www.seagate.com/nl/nl/support/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/blackarmor-maxtor/ Bottom left. It is not a driver.

Comment: @Gantendo - Ugh! 3rd party encryption… or 'how to lose your data for ever' :\ https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/external-products/blackarmor-maxtor/_shared/docs/black-armor-qsg.pdf

Comment: @Tetsujin ...made by Seagate, the reliable company that makes reliable drives with reliable software. /s if that wasn't clear....